# Why I am getting socket closed message in the get requests.get in the loop

Tags: python

I am getting the socket closed error message while calling the requests.get in the loop. What should I do here?
I am using the code from running on my Rpi: https://github.com/ferrygun/urequest/blob/main/urequest1.py

> waiting for connection...
>
> connected ip = 192.168.50.17
>
> Start reading http
>
> Socket closed
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
> line 36, in    File "", line 22, in getSignSession
> File "urequest1.py", line 250, in get   File "urequest1.py", line 131,
> in request KeyboardInterrupt:

Here is my code:
`

```
import urequest1
import urequests
import ujson
from machine import Pin
import utime
import gc
import netman

def getSignSession():
    headers = {
            'Host': ' app.workato.com',
            'User-Agent': ' Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0',
            'Accept': ' application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Accept-Language': ' en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Referer': ' https://app.workato.com/users/sign_in',
            'Content-Type': ' application/json',
            'Connection': ' keep-alive',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': ' empty',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': ' cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': ' same-origin'
        }
    response = urequest1.get('https://app.workato.com/web_api/auth_user.json', headers=headers)
    #x_csrf_token = response.cookies["XSRF-TOKEN"]
```

```
while True:
    try:
        getSignSession()
    except OSError as e:
        continue
```

Comment: Please update the question to include the whole error traceback message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated the question, the error only happens when I run the code in the loop.